Does "practiced" should be consider as expert
In the sentence:

Thus, the treatment in this book reflects our philosophy that electronics,
as currently practiced, is basically a simple art, a combination of some basic laws, rules of thumb, and a large bag
of tricks.

Does "practiced" should be consider as expert? So does "as currently practiced" can understand as "As an expert in the industry today." Is it right?

No, it uses this sense of "practice":
M-W practice
1b: to do or perform often, customarily, or habitually
So, it means those who do electronics are working at "a simple art...".

Thank you for answer.
